# Peculiar horizontal lines in 3d plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a 3d plot as using 3 2d arrays. I get the plot just fine but I want to truncate the axes using `ax.set_xlim()`

This is the original plot I have: [image]

I want to remove the long tails for each curve. I use `ax.set_xlim(0,30)` and this is the result:
[image]

I want to get rid of the extra part that is flowing out of the graph area. If I reduce the limits futher with `ax.set_xlim(0,25)`, I get something even more weird:

[image]

Ideally, I would want the x-axis to only show points until 25. How can I get rid of the extra parts?

Thanks in advance!

The code (the arrays are being read from a file):

```
    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')

    for i in range(5):
      ax.plot(E[:,i], freq[:,i], DF[:,i])

    ax.set_zlabel(filename + "$\ [eV^{-1} cm^{-3}]$")
    ax.set_xlabel("$\epsilon [eV]$")
    ax.set_ylabel("f [MHz]")
    ax.set_xlim(0,25)
    ax.set_yticks(freq[0])
    fig.savefig(filename+"3d.png", dpi = 1500, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Data file from where the data is being read: [File](https://purdue0-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/ssimha_purdue_edu/EZ6v1ekFeaJAhZIPz5Ggb3oBdfkVxnoEjoLXhYEJPOHYXA?e=3WBvOs)

Comment: Can you provide a code sample? It will be hard for people to help if they can't reproduce your issue

Comment: I edited the question to include the code.Thanks!

Comment: Okay, this is definitely better! Can you provide a sample part of the array? Perhaps the data for one of the curves

Comment: I added the data file as a OneDrive link. I'm not sure how else to include it in the post.

Comment: How do `E`, `freq`, and `D` in your code relate to the two columns in your sample file? I assume the sample data represent one of the five curves.

Comment: One the x and z axes, E and D are plotted. freq just has staggered values representing each of the separate curves. The data file just has data for the first freq curve.

Comment: Looks like a bug in `mplot3d `. If you move the 3D view around, these arbitrary lines [appear](https://imgur.com/a/Akk5QQs) and [disappear](https://imgur.com/a/xOBSsHf) depending on the view angle. Have you tried trimming your data before plotting instead of limiting the axes after plotting?

Comment: Yeah trimming works. I was wondering if I was doing anything else wrong. Let's hope the bug gets fixed. Thank you for your help!